# How can i get always last 2 hours logs by Elasticsearch Nest query C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

My question is related to  writing query  by using Nest DSL.I want to get my logs only last 2 hours. I developed a console application and I registered it as windows task. it will work per 2 hours but it should  take always 2 hours logs My code is below:

```js
            var searchResponse = EsClient().Search<Source>(sd => sd
                              .Index(IndexName)
                              .Type(TypeName)
                              .Query(q => q
                                  .Match(m => m.Field(config.GetSection("Criterias")["SearchField"]).Query(config.GetSection("Criterias")["SearchValue"])
                    )));
```

My time stamp:@timestamp:September 29th 2017, 14:56:37.903

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `bool/filter` query in order to include another `range` query on your timestamp field:

```
var searchResponse = EsClient().Search<Source>(sd => sd
                          .Index(IndexName)
                          .Type(TypeName)
                          .Query(q => q
                            .Bool(b => b
                               .Filter(
                                  bf => bf.Match(m => m.Field(config.GetSection("Criterias")["SearchField"]).Query(config.GetSection("Criterias")["SearchValue"])),
                                  bf => bf.DateRange(dr => dr
                                      .OnField("@timestamp")
                                      .GreaterThan(DateMath.Now.Subtract("2h"))
                                  )
                              )
                          )
```